# run a macro multiple times with different parameters at once

Tags: sas, sas-macro

So I have this macro: `stab_index(yearmonth,period)`.

Let's say that I have to run it 5 times (maybe more) with different parameters like this

```
 %stab_index(201601,01/2016);
 %stab_index(201602,02/2016);
 %stab_index(201603,03/2016);
 %stab_index(201604,04/2016);
 %stab_index(201605,05/2016);
```

in order to generate a adequate dataset to run another macro: `Stab_Ind_DYNAMICS`.

But I don't want to run 6 times to get the result, I would like to run all of them at once without having to fill the parameters every time.

Can someone point me in the direction of how I would set this up?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to explain more about what %STAB_INDEX does.  I could be that you don't want to "do it that way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with another macro which loops trough your list of parameters.

```
%let param1 = 201601 201602 201603 201604 201605;
%let param2 = 01/2016 02/2016 03/2016 04/2016 05/2016;
%macro loop();
    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&param1,%str( )));
        %let thisparam1=%scan(&param1,&i,%str( ));
        %let thisparam2=%scan(&param2,&i,%str( ));
        %put &thisparam1 &thisparam2;
        %stab_index(&thisparam1,&thisparam2);
    %end;
%mend loop;
%loop;
```

You first need to define your lists of parameters (I called them param1 & param2 here).

Then you can loop from 1 to the number of words and retrieve the i'th paramter from the list and use it in your stab_index macro.

> Just in case you parameters contains spaces, you can use another separator than spaces for your lists and define it with a 2nd argument in the countw function (`%sysfunc(countw(&param1,'-'))`) and a third parameter in the scan function (`%scan(&param1,&i,'-')`).

Comment: If you code `%sysfunc(countw(&param1),' ')` it tells COUNTW to use both a blank and a single quote mark as delimiters.  Because quote marks do not have a meaning in the macro language, they are part of the value.  If you want to indicate that only a blank should be a delimiter, you code it as  `%sysfunc(countw(&param1),%str( ))`

Comment: @Quentin You are right, that was a typo. I meant `%sysfunc(countw(&param1,' '))`, not `%sysfunc(countw(&param1),' ')`. Does your comment also applies to the %scan ?

Comment: Oops I copied  your typo and didn't notice it, but yes it applies to the whole macro language. So `%sysfunc(countw(&param1, ' '))`  will treat single quote as a delimiter, and so will `%scan(&param1, &i, ' ')` . In the macro language, a quote does not mean "this is a text value" because all values are text. If you add a quote mark, it is part of the value.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes your parameter values always exist within your data. If you can get your dataset down to every unique combination of `yearmonth` and `period` (how my `unique` dataset looks below), then you don't need to input anything, just let the data do the work which can accommodate changing data:

```
** create test data **;
data have0;
    year = 2016;
    do i=1 to 12;
        temp=i;
        output;
    end;
run;

data have; set have0;
    temp1 = strip(put(year,best4.))||strip(put(temp,z2.));
    yearmonth=intnx('month', input(put(temp1,6.), yymmn6.), 1)-1;
    period=yearmonth;
    format yearmonth yymmn6. period mmyys7.;
run;

** get data down to every unique combination of yearmonth and period **;
proc sort data = have out=unique(keep=yearmonth period) nodupkey;
    by yearmonth period;
run;

** create a macro string dynamically using data **;
data create_macro_string; set unique;
    macro_str=%nrstr("%stab_index")||"("||strip(put(yearmonth,yymmn6.))||","||strip(put(period,mmyys7.))||");";
    keep yearmonth period macro_str;
run;

** put all your macros into a list **;
proc sql noprint;
    select macro_str
    into: macro_list separated by " "
    from create_macro_string;
quit;

** call your macros **;
%put &macro_list.;
```

Comment: You might be interested in CALL EXECUTE.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1q1527d51eivsn1ob5hnz0yd1hx.htm